# I dont understand "AttributeError: __getitem__"

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that removes only the "r" and "b" of an image's rgb values, leaving an image of varying shades of green. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('Image.jpg')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
width, height = rgb_im.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
        im[x][y] = [0, g, 0, 255]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(im, interpolation='none')
fig.show()
```

I am very new to programming and don't understand why my code is throwing this error:

> AttributeError: __getitem__

Could anyone explain how to fix this or recommend a better solution?
`AttributeError: __getitem__`

Comment: Can you give some more info? What is the full error? What line does it show on?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? There are no doubt thousands of questions on stackoverflow pertaining to `AttributeError: __getitem__`.

Comment: Without a line number I'm not sure what in your code is throwing this error, but `__getitem__` is a builtin function that is called when you use square brackets to get an item (like in a list or dict). [Python 2 Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), [Python 3 Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: You need to create an array, im is a `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile` object, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the error is on line:

```
im[x][y] = ...
```

which would be a problem if an `Image.open()` object does not support `[]` syntax (which is implemented by `__getitem__`).

If this is true, then the fix is probably:

```
rgb_im.setpixel(...)
```